# Not been able to connect to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web-development-server

Here's my index.js code

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const appRoute = require("./route/appRoute");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");

app.use("/", appRoute);


mongoose.connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/meanDB",{
   

    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(bodyparser.json());

http.createServer(app).listen(port);



console.log("running on port ", port);
```

it is showing me following error in postman anyone can tell me the solution please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUgk1.png)

Comment: Caan you try `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: i did but still not working

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: You should catch the error and print full error messages. Is the MongoDB running?